# Query on table with nullable foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, normalization

Say I have a table with on it 5 nullable foreign keys. For every row only 1 of these has a value.

Now, this table has grown quite a bit, and contains somewhere along the lines of 2.2m records.

In most cases I'm just interested on doing queries of 'parts' of the table c.q. those records for which a certain nullable foreign key has a value. Not surprisingly just fetching the required subset takes long, using the query below: 28 seconds to fetch 1.7m records of one particular subset.

> SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Col IS NOT NULL

I'm really interested in how I can possibly speed this up and in particular if this would be possible without making changes to the data model.

Comment: Which flavour of RDBMS?  Or did you intend [sql] to mean [sql-server]?

Comment: 1.7 / 2.2 is about 75%. This indicates that your query probably has to fetch *every* disk page. An index will only help if your working set fits in core (which it probably does)

Comment: If 1.7m rows represents one sub-set, it must be way larger than the other sub-sets (which together total ~0.5m rows). You have limited options when it comes to tuning queries with such divergenet volumes of data.

Comment: Yeah, this is a corner case: tje subset really is this big :(

Comment: Are you calling this from a programming language?  When I call a database from Ruby on Rails, ActiveRecord takes a long time, although the database responds quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing which can speed up

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Col IS NOT NULL
```

is an index on Col.

However, it may take a while to transmit 1.7M records from the server to the database client, in particular if it is over the network.  The only thing you can do there is reduce the amount of data you are sending, like specifying just the fields you need in the SELECT.

Comment: This is assuming that you cannot do anything about the network connection between the client and server.

Comment: The tests I'm performing are on my local dev machine, which is an ok machine. The index is already present on the column. 

I'd much rather have multiple tables.

Comment: Also, @wildplasser may be right.  With an index the db may know which records to select, but the disk access (and the time it takes) may be similar to the non-indexed query.

Comment: I'm really saying, if you are on your local machine with no network latency to worry about, and the column is indexed, then there's not much you can do to reduce the time.

Comment: Times indeed are very similar

Comment: We should probably refactor this part of the model. We never really felt comfortable with it, but was sort of imposed.

Comment: But the problem is how much data you are getting and that the database has to look at almost all of it.  Unless you can limit the fields you are retrieving, you might still have the same issue with 1.7M records.  If you *do* select fewer fields, then refactoring into a table with just those fields will help speed up the database.

Answer (score 1):

If I couldn't change the base tables, I would create a VIEW that turns the five denormalized columns into two columns: origin and value.  So suppose you have this:

```
Table notNormal (
primaryKey,
someValue,
foreignNotNormal01,
foreignNotNormal02,
foreignNotNormal03,
foreignNotNormal04,
foreignNotNormal05
)
```

I would create this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW fixedThis AS
SELECT primaryKey, someValue, 'FKCOL01' AS foreignNotNormalOrigin, foreignNotNormal01 AS foreignNotNormalColValue
WHERE foreignNotNormal01 IS NOT NULL
UNION
 ...
 ...
SELECT primaryKey, someValue, 'FKCOL01' AS foreignNotNormalOrigin, foreignNotNormal05 AS foreignNotNormalColValue
WHERE foreignNotNormal05 IS NOT NULL
```

Then my SELECTS against fixedThis are only showing results with values in the foreign key columns, whatever they might be.

Indices are the way to go if you just want a simple speed-up, but really, you need to fix the data model.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to partition the data based upon whether those tables were null, you might speed things up a bit - all data with `Col != NULL` would be in a single partition.  Of course, that assumes that those 5 columns are the most important bit of this table.

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION MyCol1 (int)
AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (NULL)

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME MySchemeForCol1
AS PARTITION MyCol1
TO Col1FileGroup
```

Refactoring the table will improve things, though, and I'd go there before putting too much time into partitioning the data.  Partitioning like this would still keep things in the same table, but segregated on disk ... but refactoring the table into a series of linking tables would *probably* be more bang for your buck.

If you have any luck with partitioning, though, please do let everybody know & post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried joining the table with the other table that the foreign key in question references?  This will drop out all entries where the foreign key is null.
I expect the join to run very slow, but you could be pleasantly surprised.

Also, do you have an index on the foreign key in question?